# ActionScript - how to traverse objects?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Hey i wanna do something like this:

```
i=2;
_root.("process" + i)._x = var_Process_Pos_x;
```

how it is possible?, correct syntax please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [bracket operator](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#array_access) to access data members in the following manner:

```
_root["process" + i]._x = var_Process_Pos_x;
```